# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такой блок

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такой блок. Не могу понять как его реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: фоновой картинкой например

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80) или [svg](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-shapes/).

Задание фигур вёрсткой тут не подойдёт, потому что сложно будет сделать потом нормальные границы у всей фигуры в целом (в вашем примере есть границы) + если потребуется responsivness, то тоже будут лишние сложности.

Учтите, что есть принципиальные моменты, различающие svg и canvas. О них вы можете прочитать, например, [тут](http://w3pro.ru/article/svg-ili-canvas-slozhnosti-vybora)

В примере ниже я нарисовал нужную Вам фигуру при помощи canvas. Надеюсь, текст расположите уже сами.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('figure');
    if (canvas.getContext){
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0,0);
      ctx.lineTo(200,0);
      ctx.lineTo(200,100);
      ctx.lineTo(300,200);
      ctx.lineTo(650,200);
      ctx.lineTo(700,270);
      ctx.lineTo(650,300);
      ctx.lineTo(320,300);
      ctx.lineTo(200,340);
      ctx.lineTo(0,340);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="figure" width="800" height="700"></canvas>
```